# Is there a common way to contact the administrator of a .onion site?

Tags: onion-services

I have bugs to report, but there is no obvious contact information on the page itself.  I am asking if there are common places that people leave contact information or if there's some way I can leave a message for the operator based solely on the public key of their hidden service.  Know of anything?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 4):

What would one expect is that there should not be contact information available about person running **.onion** site unless the person provides those information on the website itself.